# How to prevent javascript function by getting called twicely?

Tags: javascript

am trying to call a simple javascript function like

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  performOperation();
}

function performOperation()
{
}
```

but this function getting called twicelly,I don't know how and why,can any body help me with this?

Comment: You can write console.trace() inside that function and checkout trail of how it is going called again

Comment: If you are registering ready event twice then it could also be the reason...

Comment: You might also be loading 2 jQuery versions

Comment: can you check this code in a fiddle?

Comment: @Parag Bhayani how do i  checkout that trail??

Comment: @Ma6139735: inside debugger of browser, you can open your debug bar by pressing F12 in firefox and chrome

Comment: yes i did that and and there am getting  this 'console.trace()performOperation @ App.js:239' nad there is 2 inside gray colour circle see here(http://i.stack.imgur.com/iiwHN.png)